# Show specific gmap in block based on node id

Tags: 7, views, blocks, google-maps

I am trying to show a gmap for a specific location, using the content: mapping coordinates for gmap in a view in drupal 7. The map itself shows fine in content for the page view, but if i clone it to block it shows all maps for that content. I cannot figure out how, without using php, to filter by the current node.

For example, node id 2 has coordinates so show the map for that node in the view for the block. and only node 2, not nodes 3,4,5,7.

I am really trying to do this using views and block and not php code in blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Add an argument to the view, the argument is the node ID, then you'll be able to retrieve fields and information only for the viewed node.

Example: http://through-my-eyes.be/portfolio/events/2011/04/07/drupal-government-days-2011

Comment: How do you do that in drupal 7? I have looked at contextual filters and relationships, but don't see how to check against the current node. the comparison for filtering criteria also seem to be explicit. if you've done this in d7 can you export the view for the block display and paste it here, please?

Comment: As I wrote before, create a block with a view and add an argument (Node: Nid) and extract it from URL.

Comment: That's the thing, where in d7 do you add the argument? Your example is EXACTLY what i'm trying to do, but I don't see arguments - what are they called now in d7?

Comment: It's when you create the view.
I'm not using D7 yet but the term 'argument' should be in Views 3.
I'll install it tomorrow on a test instance and report back here.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I am sure I must be overlooking something...

Comment: Argument is 'Contextual filters' in the advanced section of your views.
There, add the 'Content: Nid', then select 'Provide default value', then 'Content ID from URL' and it's done.

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I needed. Thank you so, so much! :D